# Send notifications after a record is created in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, notifications

Is it possible to send out a notification after creating a record?

I have a game model and a user model, the two are connected by fields labeled captain_id, and organizer_id (who are both references to user IDs). Now what I'd like is to be able send notifications to both users about the newly created game model.

I have been searching everywhere, and I will continue to do so, but I haven't found much in regards to posts/tutorials/videos similar to my predicament.

Comment: the Events docs didn't trigger any thoughts on the matter? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Laravel 5.5 I would highly suggest into the [Laravel Events documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events). Looking into the Model class (Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model), when an object is created it fires an event (specifically [fireModelEvent](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_fireModelEvent)). What you can do is register a Notification handler on that specific model event and have that handler send out the notification you want (i.e. SMS, E-Mail, Slack, etc.)

I would do the following when you want to handle a specific event (I used the User model in my example):

1. Run `php artisan make:event UserCreated`
2. Add `uses Notifiable` to the User model.
3. Create a variable on the User model.

   protected $dispatchesEvents = [
   'created' => UserCreated::class
   ];
4. Implement the `broadcastOn()` function in your newly created Event to do what you want it to do.

Comment: Why the broadcastOn() method? There's nothing about it in the documentation.

Comment: @Gazzer When you create a new Event using php artisan make:event, it generates a basic PHP class with the broadcastOn() method. This is the method I am talking about. You have to specify the channels where you want to broadcast "on" in this method.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Jon's answer with an example. You can add a boot method on your model that will fire on model events (like saved/created).

```
protected static function boot(){
static::saved(function($thisModel){
        if (($thisModel->wasRecentlyCreated == true) && ($thisModel->attributes['status'] == 1)){
            $thisModel->send_created_mail($thisModel->id);
        }
        else{
            if ($thisModel->isDirty('status')) {
                $thisModel->send_status_mail($thisModel->attributes['status']);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

$thisModel will be the instance of the model that is being saved, so you can access it's attributes. If your model extends a base model or something similar be sure to add parent::boot() before static::saved()